# How do I process HTMLCollection {}?

Tags: javascript, jsdom

I'm using JSDOM to set up html for processing.

```
async function processHtml(input) {
  const dom = new JSDOM(input)
  const tables = dom.window.document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')
  for (let x of tables) {
    
    if (x.getElementsByTagName('tr').length === 1) {
      const test = [...x.getElementsByTagName('tr')]
      console.log("Line 32:", test)
    } else {
      console.log("Line 32:", x.getElementsByTagName('tr').length)
    }
  }
}
```

What I'm getting from this algorithm is:

```
Line 32: HTMLTableRowElement {}
Line 32: 11
Line 32: 10
Line 32: 10
Line 32: HTMLTableRowElement {}
Line 32: HTMLTableRowElement {}
Line 32: 11
Line 32: 12
Line 32: 3
Line 32: HTMLTableRowElement {}
```

I'm stuck. These are not regular objects?
How do I process them?

**Note**

How do I use DOM methods on HTMLTableRowElement { }?

**Update 1: Change function**

I want to see what I'm working with here.

```
async function processHtml(input) {
  const dom = new JSDOM(input)
  const tables = dom.window.document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')

  Object.keys(tables).forEach(x => console.log(tables[x]))
}
```

This function returns:

```
HTMLTableSectionElement {}
HTMLTableSectionElement {}
HTMLTableSectionElement {}
HTMLTableSectionElement {}
HTMLTableSectionElement {}
HTMLTableSectionElement {}
HTMLTableSectionElement {}
HTMLTableSectionElement {}
HTMLTableSectionElement {}
HTMLTableSectionElement {}
```

So it seems like this is going to be a pattern.
I haven't a clue what tools are available to help me deal with this properly.

Some ideas on cutting through this would be appreciated. Thank you.

**Update 2: If someone else finds this question useful**

This algorithm brought me closer to the solution I was seeking. Thanks to
the accepted answer.

```
async function processHtml(input) {
  const dom = new JSDOM(input)
  Array.from(dom.window.document.querySelectorAll('table tbody')).forEach((tbody, i) => {
    if (i === 4 || i === 5) {
      console.log(`========= ${i} ============`)
      Array.from(tbody.querySelectorAll('td')).forEach((td, j) => {
        if (j === 0 || j === 1){
          console.log(`[${j}]`, td.innerHTML)
        }
      })
      console.log('===========================')
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some options. First of, if you want to iterate through them with their default iteration behavior, you need to use `for of`, like you did.

If you want to also use Array methods, you can convert `NodeList` or `HTMLLiveCollection` to an array by:

- old way:
  `Array.prototype.slice.call(...)`
- es6:
  `Array.from(...)`

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('table tbody')).forEach(tbody=>{
    //do something with tbody
    Array.from(tbody.querySelectorAll("tr")).forEach(tr => {
        //do something with tr
    })
})
```

In the above example, change `document` to `dom.window.document` and if you'd like, you could have used `getElementsByTagName` method.

`getElementsByClassName` and `getElementsByTagName` return  live `HTMLCollection`, meaning returned object is array like but not an array, and gets updated as you change the DOM. `querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList`, similar to `HTMLCollection` but does NOT update. They both have legacy methods like `item` to get the node by index, but I suggest converting them to arrays first.

In the example above, instead of the inner `forEach` loop, you could have also used `Array.from(tbody.childNodes)` and check if a given items `tagName` property is equal to `TR` or not and proceed accordingly.

You have too many options depending on what you like, I suggest going through MDN for [Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) and [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) docs.

Comment: Thank you. This led me into the solutions I needed. The tip about tbody.childNodes was a particularly helpful tip.

Comment: Np, there is a lot more out there that might be better suited for your case, such as `children` property. As far as I can see, you are only interested in "element" nodes, which means elements with `element.nodeType === 1`, in that case `children` is better than `childNodes` because `childNodes` will returns textNodes which have nodeType of 3. This is the reason why left the links on MDN, gl.

Comment: I'm working at zeroing down to the specific text and retrieving that data. I'm scraping wikipedia for data.

Comment: In that case, if you do not care about which node the specific text belongs to, you can loop through the tbodies and check `tbody.textContent`, which will return a `String`, you can then call `match` or `Regex.prototype.exec` on the string itself

Comment: That's cool. I'm actually trying to relate the retrieved data to the parent span. I'm slowly working my way through. Pointing out Nodes and Elements as the place to focus was helpful.

Comment: I would like to emphasize that this answer was very illuminating and helped me learn a great deal that I did not know before I started working on this problem. Array.from() created an excellent jumping-off point for me to find more elegant solutions to a layered problem. I had not properly understood the relevance of nodes in the DOM before this. Thanks much.

Answer (score -1):

`let x of tables` will loop over the values of **all** the enumerable properties of the object, including things like `length`. Switch out `of` for `in` to get the names.

You only want the numerical indexes. Use a regular `for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++)` loop.

Comment: Are the Array.prototype functions available to use on these HTMLCollection objects?

Comment: The names I get are just a list of key values. How do I access the underlying layers?
Eg. console.log(x) returns:
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
item
namedItem
length

Comment: I didn't say the names would be useful, that is just to demonstrate why a `for of` loop doesn't work. Do what I said in the second paragraph. Just use an absolutely bog-standard [for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).

Comment: Is this what you are suggesting?
  for (let x in tables) {
    for (let i =0 ; i < x.getElementsByTagName('tr').length; i++) {
      console.log(x.getElementsByTagName('tr')[i])
    }    
}

The response is not encouraging: "(node:2602) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: x.getElementsByTagName is not a function"

Comment: `x[i]`. The index goes on the object you're accessing.

Comment: "TypeError: x[i].getElementsByTagName is not a function" ???
I'm not comprehending your suggestion.                              
If I use Object.keys(tables).forEach(x => console.log(tables[x]))
I at least get back instances of HTMLTableSectionElement {}. I don't know what to do with them though, which is the meat of my question.